# Nginx redirect specific path to a subdomain outside of Wordpress

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I have a main website using **Wordpress** powered by **Nginx** (using HTTPS `https://example.com`) and I need to redirect a specific path to another server, responding to the subdomain `http://files.example.com` (no SSL).

Whatever I try, rewrite or redirect 301, I land on Wordpress' 404 error page. I think I can't get outside of Wordpress location within my Nginx configuration :

```
server {
    listen            443 ssl;
    listen            [::]:443;
    server_name       example.com;

    root              /var/www/wordpress;
    index             index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log        /var/log/nginx/example.access.log;
    error_log         /var/log/nginx/example.error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$is_args$args =404;
    }

    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php break;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log    off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include       fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass  php-wp;
    }

    location /files {
        rewrite ^/files(.*)$ http://files.example.com/files$1 redirect;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `if` block

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php break;
}
```

will rewrite any request for any file that is missing at the `/var/www/wordpress` folder to WordPress `index.php`. There is no need for this `if` block at all, remove it. Last argument of [`try_files`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive can be either a new URI or a HTTP error code, but you are trying to use both. Correct your root location block to

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

For redirecting you don't need a separate `location` block, just use

```
rewrite ^/files http://files.example.com$request_uri redirect;
```

for HTTP 302 temporary redirection or

```
rewrite ^/files http://files.example.com$request_uri permanent;
```

for HTTP 301 permanent redirection.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer ! That's working perflectly and it's more clear in my mind.